# Gradle with non-standard named source sets - how do I make them available to the test classes?

Tags: java, build, gradle, source-sets

I have a (legacy) Java project which I'm re-configuring to build with Gradle. The build should, eventually, output a number of `jar` archives, so I've divided to split up the source into source sets that correspond to the subdivision of the output into archives.

The file tree looks something like this:

```
- project root
    - src
        - setOne
             - java
                  - ...
             - resources
                  - ...
        - setTwo
             - java
                  - ...
        - setThree
             - java
                  - ...
             - resources
                  - ...
        - test
             - java
                  - ...

    - build.gradle
```

and in `build.gradle` I have the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    setOne
    setTwo {
        compileClasspath += setOne.output
    }
    setThree

    test
}

dependencies {
    setOne group: 'foo', name: 'bar', version: '1.0'
}

// Setup dependencies so that compileJava compiles all source sets
// while avoiding cyclic dependencies for main and test
sourceSets.matching { ss -> 
    !(ss.getName().contains('test') || ss.getName().contains('main')) 
}.each { ss ->
    compileJava.dependsOn ss.getCompileJavaTaskName()
}
```

When I try to build this, I get a bunch of warnings from the `compileSetTwoJava` target about some classes not being resolved - referring to classes from the `foobar` library imported to `setOne`. I assume this is because Gradle only gives `setTwo` access to the classes built in `setOne` - but why isn't it able to resolve the dependencies for the classes imported from `setOne` in the process?

How do I set up this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was just as easy as I thought it ought to be - if you just start out the right way. Definining

```
setTwo {
    classPath += setOne.runtimeClasspath // instead of setOne.output
}
```

solves the problem.

**UPDATE:**

It seems even better to do it among the dependencies, where one can do

```
dependencies {
    setTwo sourceSets.setOne.output
}
```

and get it working.